# enumitem nextline style: nested item shouldn't start on description label's line

Tags: lists, line-breaking, enumitem, description, nesting

I use `enumitem` description style `nextline` to emulate a sort of TOC entry with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{DLdescription}[1][*]{%
  \newcommand{\DLitem}[2][]{%
    \item[##1\hfill\emph{##2}]
  }
  \begin{description}[style=nextline,leftmargin=#1]%
}{\end{description}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{DLdescription}
  \DLitem[dleft1]{dright1}
    blah blah
    \begin{itemize}
    \item nested item correctly starts on its own line
    \end{itemize}
      \DLitem[dleft2]{dright2}
    % nothing before itemize
    \begin{itemize}
    \item nested item shouldn't start on description label's line!
    \end{itemize}
  \end{DLdescription}

\end{document}
```

The trouble comes on the *second* description item which starts straight away with an `itemize`: the nested item appears on the same line :-(

[image: output of code sample]

A workaround found elsewhere suggests to append a `\hfill` to the relevant label, in my case that would patch command `DLitem` with

```
\item[##1\hfill\emph{##2}]\hfill
```

which, gives a non satisfactory results, as too much vertical space is added between the description label's line and the first nested item:

[image: output of patched code]

How to obtain the result in the second image without any extra vertical space?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misusing the `nextline` style. I would suggest that you do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\DLitem}[2][]{%
 \item[#1]\hfill \emph{#2}\par}

\newenvironment{DLdescription}[1][*]
 {\begin{description}[leftmargin=#1]}
 {\end{description}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{DLdescription}
  \DLitem[dleft1]{dright1}
    blah blah
    \begin{itemize}
    \item nested item correctly starts on its own line
    \end{itemize}
      \DLitem[dleft2]{dright2}
    % nothing before itemize
    \begin{itemize}
    \item nested item shouldn't start on description label's line!
    \end{itemize}
  \end{DLdescription}

\end{document}
```

You can adjust locally `\parskip` is you want less space after the first line.

Comment: Very neat, indeed! A last optimization could be inserting a `\parskip` only if a nested environment is detected, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a manual adjustment that works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem

\newcommand{\DLitem}[2][]{%
  \item[#1\hfill\emph{#2}]
}
\newenvironment{DLdescription}[1][*]{%
  \begin{description}[style=nextline,leftmargin=#1]%
}{\end{description}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{DLdescription}
  \DLitem[dleft1]{dright1}
    blah blah
    \begin{itemize}
    \item nested item correctly starts on its own line
    \end{itemize}
      \DLitem[dleft2]{dright2}
    \hfill\\[\dimexpr-2\baselineskip-\topsep]
    \begin{itemize}
    \item nested item shouldn't start on description label's line!
    \end{itemize}
  \end{DLdescription}

\end{document}​
```

Inserting a blank line `\null\hfill`, followed by a vertical skip equivalent to the start of the description *plus* an extra `\baselineskip`: `\\[\dimexpr-2\baselineskip-\topsep]`

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like a patch for my `\DLitem` command. I can't put your solution there as it screws other items with some text before any nested environment...